# button visible on div hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to make the button visible when the user hovers on the div yet not working.

```css
#box{
background-color: red;
}

.btn {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  display: none;
}

.foo:hover + .btn{

display: inline-block;
}
/*ignore from here*/
.foo {
    position:relative;
    width:500px;
    height:500px;
    
}
.foo img {
    width:100%;
    vertical-align:top;
}
.foo:after, .foo:before {
    position:absolute;
    opacity:0;
    transition: all 0.3s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
}
.foo:after {
    content:'\A';
    width:100%; height:100%;
    top:0; left:0;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}
.foo:before {
    content: attr(data-content);
    
    color:#fff;
    z-index:1;
    padding:4px 10px;
    text-align:center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  
     
}
.foo:hover:after, .foo:hover:before {
    opacity:1;
 
}

/*ignore to here*/
```

```html
<div id="box" class="foo" data-content="Caption">
      <button class="btn">view</button>
      </div>
```

the button display is initially set to `none`. and when the users hover on the div it is set to `inline-block`. what can I do to get the button on top and visible when the user hovers on the div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change your + sign to a > sign. The button is inside the div, not on the same level as it. + is for items on the same level

```
   .foo:hover > .btn{
      display: inline-block;
    }
```

Comment: happy to help!!

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there, but to select the button, you need `>` (child combinator) to select the child of the hovered `div`. Use `+` when selecting *subsequent siblings*.

```css
/*ignore from here*/

.foo {
  position: relative;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
}

.foo img {
  width: 100%;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.foo:after,
.foo:before {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
}

.foo:after {
  content: '\A';
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

.foo:before {
  content: attr(data-content);
  color: #fff;
  z-index: 1;
  padding: 4px 10px;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.foo:hover:after,
.foo:hover:before {
  opacity: 1;
}


/*ignore to here*/

#box {
  background-color: red;
}

.btn {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  display: none;
}

.foo:hover>.btn {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="box" class="foo" data-content="Caption">
  <button class="btn">view</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

> The + combinator selects adjacent siblings. This means that the second element directly follows the first, and both share the same parent.`.btn` is'nt sibling for `.foo`,but it is his children. so remove `+` selector.

**Change :**

```
.foo:hover + .btn{
```

**To:**

```
.foo:hover .btn{
```

```css
.foo {
    position:relative;
    width:500px;
    height:500px;
    
}
.foo img {
    width:100%;
    vertical-align:top;
}
.foo:after, .foo:before {
    position:absolute;
    opacity:0;
    transition: all 0.3s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
}
.foo:after {
    content:'\A';
    width:100%; height:100%;
    top:0; left:0;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}
.foo:before {
    content: attr(data-content);
    
    color:#fff;
    z-index:1;
    padding:4px 10px;
    text-align:center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  
     
}
.foo:hover:after, .foo:hover:before {
    opacity:1;
 
}

#box{
background-color: red;
}

.btn {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  display: none;
}

.foo:hover  .btn{
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="box" class="foo" data-content="Caption">
  <button class="btn">view</button>
</div>
```